# UIScrollView not zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

So, I have this `UIScrollView` that was doing just fine with zooming at first. I have the minimum and maximum zoom scales set and the necessary delegate method set up `-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView;`. Originally I had two subviews set up on it (one a small one of a ball), and obviously, one would zoom out and in where the other didn't (the ball view). I wanted to change this so that they both scale correctly, so I added the smaller view (ball) to the other's list of subviews. However, now there is no zooming. I can post code if necessary, but I was wondering if this issue sounds familiar to anyone and if they have an answer to offer.

EDIT: here's the code

header file

```
@interface NumberLineScroll : UIScrollView {

    NumberLine* nline;

    id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;


- (NumberLine*)getLine;

@end
```

Main file

```
#import "NumberLineScroll.h"

@implementation NumberLineScroll

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        nline = [[NumberLine alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2100, 400)];
        [self addSubview:nline];

        self.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
        self.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    }
    return self;
 }

- (NumberLine*)getLine {return nline;}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}


- (void)dealloc {
    [nline release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

This is the scroll view. The nline is just a view with the ball view and a line drawn during `drawRect`. Here's the method implementations in the delegate class:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {}

- (void)doTest {NSLog(@"test");}

-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {return [nline getLine];}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

    NSLog(@"Zoom ended");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    Ball* ball = [[nline getLine] getBall];
    CGPoint newCenter = ball.center;
    newCenter.y = ball.center.y * scrollView.zoomScale;
    newCenter.x = ball.center.x * scrollView.zoomScale;
    [[nline getLine] changeBalLoc:newCenter];
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: it will only work for simulator. not working on device.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something about managing subview when zoomIn/Out going on placed over the UIScrollView

take care two things firstly return that largeSubview(contains ball view as subview) on zooming time from below delegate method.

```
-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
   return largeSubvew
  //here that view contains smallView(ball) too as mentioned you changed
}
```

Manage small view's position as you ZoomIn/Out scrollView.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 CGPoint newCenter = smallerViewCenter;
 //smallerViewCenter contains the center point of smallerView(say ball),has set at load time, and only once
 newCenter.y = smallerView.y * scrollView.zoomScale;
 //new center is calculated on original position
 newCenter.x = smallerView.x * scrollView.zoomScale;
 smallerView.center = newCenter;

 }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! The `scrollViewDidZoom` was just what I needed. Thank you

Comment: EDIT: looks like I jumped the gun a little on this. The second and first methods are implemented, but neither are getting called when I use the pinch gesture on the simulator.

Comment: @RaysonK oks and on Device they called ..?

Comment: @Kamarshad the methods? Exactly what you called them

Comment: @RaysonK could be please explain your problem in details...?

Comment: @RaysonK `scrollViewDidZoom` in this method your getting ball and then setting center this is totally wrong, you should have kept center point in any (`CGPoint`)global variable as you have added Subviews over the  `UIScrollView` and then use it.

Comment: Okay, well the problem at this point is that the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` method isn't getting called. I've implemented `scrollViewWillBeginZooming` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming`, which both get called, just not the one that has you returning the subview.

Comment: Probably should mention that I'm now implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate` in place of a custom delegate